# Cannot get to the 3rd URL for query with Try, Except

Tags: python

It does not go to the 3rd url -

```
try:
        "code here..."
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
    pass  # doesn't pass to try:
```

Here is the code-

```
import requests

try:
    for url in ['google.com', 'skypeassets.com', 'yahoo.com']:

        http = ("http://")
        url2 = (http + url)
        page = requests.get(url2)

        if page.status_code == 200:
            print('Success!')
        elif page.status_code == 404:
            print('Not Found.')

except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
    print("This site cannot be reached")
        pass
```

OUTPUT-

Success!
This site cannot be reached
(for 3rd url - should say - Success!, but skipping)

Comment: Your try-except should be *inside* the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `try` `except` can able to catch only one exception at a time inside of its body or block. 
That means you have to use it inside your `for` loop.

```
import requests

for url in ['google.com', 'skypeassets.com', 'yahoo.com']:
    try:
        http = "http://"
        url2 = http + url
        page = requests.get(url2)

        if page.status_code == 200:
            print('Success!')
        elif page.status_code == 404:
            print('Not Found.')

    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        print("This site cannot be reached")
```